# PHP file upload into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I have created a form as follows. What I'm doing is

1. User is selecting a client from drop down list and uploading file. When he clicks on Add button the page will redirect to Confirm.php.
2. The Confirm.php will show whatever the user has given the input i.e, Client name and name of the file which he has uploaded.
3. In Confirm.php the user is submitting the form and it should add to the database, **except file upload remaining fields are adding to the database. In database, file upload field is showing empty. Please somebody solve this problem.
   And I'm not getting how to access path variable from Confirm.php into Add.php.**

I'm new to the php. So any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

**Home.php**

```
<form action="Confirm.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
    <label> <span>Client</span>
      <select class="required" name="client">
             <?php
mysql_connect ("localhost","root","");
                    mysql_select_db ("eservice");
                    $select="eservice";
                    if (isset ($select)&&$select!="")
                    {
    $select=$_POST ['NEW'];
                    }
            ?>
          <?php
    $list=mysql_query("select * from client");
                    while($row_list=mysql_fetch_assoc($list))
                                            {
           ?>
          <?php $ct = $row_list['cname'];?>
          <option value="<?php echo $ct; ?>"<?php if($ct==$select){ echo "selected"; } ?> > <?php echo $ct; ?></option>
          <?php } ?>
      </select>
    </label>

    <label> <span>SRN</span>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","eservice");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$sql="Select * from main";
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  $rowcount++;
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
<input name="srn" type="text" id="srn" size="15" readonly="readonly" maxlength="40" value="<?php echo "$rowcount"; ?>"/>
</label>
    </div>
        <label>
            <span>File upload</span>
            <input type="file" name ="filename" required>
        </label>
    <button id='send' type='submit'>Add</button>
<button id='clear' type='reset'>Reset</button>
</form>
```

And this is my cofirmation page

**Confirm.php**

```
  <form action="Add.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
<label> <span>Client</span>
    <?php include_once('dbconn.php'); ?>
     <input name="client" type="text" id="client" size="15" readonly="readonly" maxlength="40" value="<?php echo $_POST['client']; ?>"/>
   </label>

        <label>
            <span>File upload</span>
    <?php  $path = '';
$folder = "Folder/";
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']))  
{   
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $folder.$_FILES['filename']['name'])) 
    {
    $path = $folder . $_FILES['filename']['name'];
    } 
    else 
    {
     $path = '';
    };
} 
else 
{
      $path = '';
}; ?>
        <input name ="filename" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $_FILES['filename']['name']; ?>"/>
        </label>
    <button id='clear' type='reset'>Back</button>
<button id='send' type='submit'>Add</button>
</form>
```

**dbconn.php**

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
$selected = mysql_select_db("eservice",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select newsite database");
?>
```

Here I'm adding the uploaded file into the phpmyadmin.

**Add.php**

```
<?php
include_once('dbconn.php');
session_start();
$_SESSION['example']='Session Created';

 $client = $_POST['client']; // required

 if($client !='')
 {
$insQry = "Insert into `main` (client,upload) Values ('$client','$path')";
    $insertQ = mysql_query($insQry);
    if($insertQ!=''){
        echo "<h2>Data inserted successfully...</h2>";
    } else {
        echo "<h2>Not added</h2>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: did you try to include add.php in confirm.php in place of dbconn.php

Comment: I tried it but still the same error

Comment: Disabled fields are not posted to your server. So you have to used `readonly` instead of `disabled`.

Comment: Yeah I set that to readonly. Now the data is inserting to database except File upload field. I checked in db, File upload field is empty. Thank you.

Comment: And I'm still getting this error                                 Notice: Undefined index: filename in if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']))

Comment: Please somebody help me. Now the data is inserting into the db except file upload and also I'm getting this error.                           Notice: Undefined index: filename in if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])).

Comment: Uploaded files are only available for a single PHP instance/request cycle.

Comment: I didn't get you. @hardik solanki

Comment: So you can't pass file data in to another page.

Comment: You need to store your file or images in another folder for temporary and then you cam moved your this files or images to your require folder.

Comment: So how to achieve this file upload task through confirmation page. Thanks.

Comment: You need to move your file upload code to `Confirm.php` file instead of `Add.php` file.

Comment: Yeah I moved to Confirm.php and I've one doubt i.e, how to access that path variable in Add.php?

Comment: You can store your file path to one variable and put it into your `readonly` field on `Confirm.php` file.

Comment: Please explain in detail. Thanks.

Comment: See I'm storing file upload path in $path variable in Confirm.php and I'm accessing $path variable in Add.php but it's not coming. It's giving an error i.e,Undefined variable: path in  $insQry = "Insert into `main` (client,fy,sd,fd,upload,assignto) Values ('$client','$fy','$sd','$fd','$path','$at')";

Comment: too many mysql and mysqli connections remove all and make it as unique connection

Comment: How you're saying I'm not understanding? How to achieve it man?

Answer (score 0):

Undefined Index means if that index is not set or empty...you have to check is it empty or not.

add condition in filename error

```
if ( $_FILES['filename']['error'] == 0 ){
///your uploading code
}
```

and for post veriable check it is isset or not, use ternary operator:-

```
$client =isset( $_POST['client'])?$_POST['client']:'';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `confirm.php` code should be

```
<form action="Add.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
<label> <span>Client</span>
    <?php include_once('dbconn.php'); ?>
     <input name="client" type="text" id="client" size="15" readonly="readonly" maxlength="40" value="<?php echo $_POST['client']; ?>"/>
   </label>

        <label>
            <span>File upload</span>
    <?php  $path = '';
$folder = "Folder/";
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']))  
{   
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $folder.$_FILES['filename']['name'])) 
    {
    $path = $folder . $_FILES['filename']['name'];
    } 
    else 
    {
     $path = '';
    };
} 
else 
{
      $path = '';
}; ?>
        <input name ="filename" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $_FILES['filename']['name']; ?>"/>
<input name ="path" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $path; ?>"/>
        </label>
    <button id='clear' type='reset'>Back</button>
<button id='send' type='submit'>Add</button>
</form>
```

You can get your hidden field value on `add.php` using `$path = $_POST['path']`

Comment: I tried, except file upload remaining fields are adding to the db. And I'm getting this error  Notice: Undefined index: path in  $path   = $_POST['path'];

Comment: Did you add hidden field in your confirm.php file??

Comment: Hi, now I'm doing file extension validation in file uploading and I need your help. $allowed =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg', 'pdf');
$filename = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
    echo 'Please upload correct file';
}
I added this into my Confirm.php. But I want file extension should be checked in the Home.php while uploading. I'm trying to add into the Home.php but it's not coming. It's showing Undefined index filename error. So how do I achieve this?